# Ads Changing for every 3-5 seconds in an activity of Android Application

Tags: java, android, web-services, ads

I am developing one android application in which i have implemented the 10 ads in one activity using web services. Now, i want to give the timeline for changing those ads for every 3 to 5 seconds. Please help with the sample code/links. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just working with **Countdown timer**

Schedule a countdown until a time in the future, with regular notifications on intervals along the way. Example of showing a 30 second countdown in a text field:

```
new CountdownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

## Further more..

Answer (score 1):

`TimerTask.schedule()` will solve your problem.

Please google for more information.

Comment: Note that with the Google API for the Google AdCloud there is a hard coded limit (for good reasons).

Answer (score 1):

You should use AlarmManager or Timer service for doing it it is execute in every 3-5 second.

I have also make a function of using alarm manager auto logout if user ideal for 5 min then it is logout.
public static void autoLogOut(Context context) {

```
    MyAlarmService.mContext = context;
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, myIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService("alarm");

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, (5 * 60));
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);

    // Toast.makeText(context, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

it is execute after if user ideal for 5 min.